# 403 forbidden while setting domain name in cookies

Tags: cookies, subdomain, http-status-code-403

I am getting 403 forbidden error in screen while setting domain name in cookies for example my domain name is [www.beta-farms.demo.com](http://www.beta-farms.demo.com) , [www.alpha-farms.demo.com](http://www.alpha-farms.demo.com) and [www.farms.demo.com](http://www.farms.demo.com) , now you can see ".demo.com" is common in all the domain name, I set cookies in this domain ".demo.com". but it's giving 403 forbidden.(  but when I using vpn it's working fine ) - please let me know if any one have some idea to solve this.

how to solve this issue